# Omit "> 0" in conditional?

Tags: c++, c, coding-style

I have recently inherited an old project to make some optimization and add new features. In this project I have seen this type of condition all over the code:

```
if (int_variable)
```

instead of

```
if (int_variable > 0)
```

I have used the first option only with `boolean` type of variables.

**Do you think the first option is a "correct" way to check if a number is positive?**

Comment: If the type of `int_variable` is actually `int`, no. If it's `unsigned`, yes.

Comment: In both C and C++ any non-zero value is considered true. Negative values are non-zero too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

negative numbers evaluate to `true` also,so you should go with `if (int_variable > 0)` to check if a number is positive.

Comment: In C they do not evaluate to anything - not sure about C++. In a condition, they are just considered true (but not the `_Bool` constant `_True`). This is true for any non-zero number, not only for negative values.

Answer (score 3):

No. The first option is a correct way to check if a number is non-zero.

Answer (score 2):

Any non-zero value will be considered `true`, so your version with `>` is a bit sketchy if the variable truly is `int`, i.e. signed. For clarity I prefer to make that explicit in many cases, i.e. write

```
if (int_variable != 0)
```

This is perhaps a bit convoluted (basically computing a Boolean where one can be automatically inferred), I would never use `if (bool_variable == true)` for instance but I think the integer case makes the test clearer. Reading the two cases out loud works way better for the integer.

Answer (score 2):

`if (int_variable)` has the same meaning as `if (int_variable != 0)`.

This is not the same as `if (int_variable > 0)` unless you otherwise know that the value will never be negative.

Answer (score 1):

When using an integer value as a truth value in C, zero yields `false` while any non-zero value yields `true`.

In your case, assuming int_variable is signed, `(int_variable)` is *not* equivalent to `(int_variable > 0)` since `int_variable` being negative will yield `true` and `false`, respectively.

---

So

```
if (int_variable) { … }
```

is *not* a correct way of checking whether `int_variable` is positive.

Answer (score 1):

In C any expression which evaluates to integer `0` or a *null pointer* is considered false. Anything else is true.

So basically something like

```
int i = ...;
if ( i )
```

Test if `i` is 0. However, if `i` is negative, the condition will also be true, so this is no replacement for `i > 0`. **Unless** `i` is `unsigned`. Simply because they cannot be negative. But your compiler may warn about such constructs as they often show a wrong concept.

Coming to coding style, `if ( i )` is bad style if you are really comparing to the value `0`. You better compare explicitly: `if ( i != 0 )`. However, if `i` contains some boolean result, you should use a "speaking" name (e.g. `isalpha('A')` to use a `ctypes.h` function instead of a variable) and do not compare. Compare the readbility:

```
char ch = ...;

if ( isalpha(ch) )

if ( isalpha(ch) != 0 )
```

For the latter you have to think a second about the comparison - unnecessarily.

Comment: Is this true even on architectures where `NULL != 0x0`?

Comment: @Mr.E: That's why I wrote "_null pointer constant_" C (not sure about C++, but quite positive it is similar) does not require a null pointer constant to be "all bits zero".

Comment: I knew about NULL not 0, but never heard of 2  different integer values being `false`. Thanks

Comment: @Mr.E: Where do I mention two different integer values? A null pointer is **not** an integer. In C, `NULL` is commonly `(void *)0`, thus a pointer. And even if not, the value `0` only becomes a null pointer constant in pointer-context. Note that actually the macro `NULL` cannot be different from `0` for this reason. This does not mean, however, a null pointer constant has to have "all bits zero". This is what I (possibly in error) assumed you asked.

Comment: I got it now, thank you. I wasn't getting that `(void*)0` not necessary means all bits zero, and thus why I thought there where 2 "integer values" as false (Thought something like `NULL = (void*)15`)

Comment: @Mr.E: If you know languages like Pascal/Modula or Python, you know about the special keyword/objects to tag an invalid pointer/reference. C++11 has finally learned, too (`nullptr`), there is need to get away from this special semantics of the integer `0` for pointers. Of course that does not mean there is still need for a special encoding to tag a _null pointer_ and "all bits zero" is a reasonable value for many CPUs (special "compare to zero" instructions, etc. It is just that this should not be on the higher abstration level.